# ¿Como puedo validar que solo se seleccione 1 elemento de una lista usando GestureRecognizers en un Frame?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Estoy Desarrollando un módulo con Xamarin Forms usando MVVM. En este módulo estoy cargando un ObservableCollection dentro de un ListView, y dentro de este tengo alojado un Frame como contenedor usando el componente GestureRecognizers para que reconozca el tacto del Frame y así abra otra Página.
El problema es que se pueden tocar dos elementos del Frame a la vez, entonces, se abren 2 páginas, y necesito validar que solo se pueda seleccionar 1 Frame.
¿Alguna Sugerencia?

Dejo el código del Formulario

```
<ListView
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                SelectionMode="None"
                SeparatorVisibility="None"
                CachingStrategy = "RecycleElementAndDataTemplate">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ViewCell>

                            <Frame
                                Margin="3"
                                HasShadow="True"
                                CornerRadius="10"
                                Padding="20,15"
                                BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">

                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers
                                    NumberOfTapsRequiredProperty="1"
                                    >

                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding SelectMenuCommand}"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="{Binding NumberTap}"
                                        >

                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>

                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icono}" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="20" Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="0"></Image>

                                    <Label x:Name="lblDescripcion" Text="{Binding DescripcionCorta}" 
                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           FontSize="Small"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           TextColor="Black"
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>

                                    <Image Source="ic_press" Grid.Column="2"></Image>

                                </Grid>

                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Código del Comando SelectMenuCommand :

```
if (NumberTap == 1)
            {

                if (this.Proceso == 9)
                {
                    Color = ColorTap;
                    MainViewModel.GetInstance().UnMenu = new UnMenuViewModel(User);
                    NumberTap = 10;
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new frmUnMenu());
                    NumberTap = 1;
                    Color = ColorDefecto;
                }
                else if (this.Proceso == 6)
                {
                    Color = ColorTap;
                    MainViewModel.GetInstance().GuardarPallet = new GuardarPalletViewModel(User);
                    NumberTap = 10;
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new frmGuardarPallet());
                    NumberTap = 1;
                    Color = ColorDefecto;
                }
              }
```

Comment: puedes usar binding en tu view model?

Comment: pero binding a qué?

Comment: talves no deberias usar listview, sino collection view, este tiene SelectionMode="Single"